# Are there classes of Kagune or they are all differents?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I've just watched the first season of Tokyo Ghoul anime, and in one episode the subtitle translation made a note where it said some Ghoul had a Kagune related with speed or something like that, which seemed to imply there were classes of kagunes. With the exception of Hinami who inherited traits from her father and mother, all the kagunes shown in the first season appear to be different. My question then is, are there classes of Kagunes or they are all differents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [four different kagune types](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Kagune#Rc_Types), which depend on kakuhou position in body:
[image]

- **Ukaku** - fast kagune, capable of distant attacks, but ukaku ghouls get tired quickly due to RC cells depletion;
- **Koukaku** - high density kagune, heavy, hence slow, but with high defensive capabilities;
- **Rinkaku** - flexible kagune in form of tentacles, good for close combat offense, but not really sturdy. Its owner also has improved regeneration.
- **Bikaku** - kagune with balanced speed, offensive and defensive capabilities.

Hinami is one of rare exceptions, she is [Chimera](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Chimera_kagune), having hybrid kagune. This is really rare type of kagune.

Answer (score 1):

"Speed type" is probably a translation of Ukaku (Literally: "Feather-red"). Ukaku is one of the four types of kagunes (Ukaku, Koukaku, Rinkaku and Bikaku).

Each type of kagune is considered to be "stronger" than one type, and "weaker" than one type, e.g., rinkaku is generally best against a koukaku, but it's worst against a bikaku.

You can read more about the types on the [wiki](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Kagune).